# Listener support for CMT after commit/rollback

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, weblogic11g

I have a requirement where I need to know when a container managed transaction commits the transaction for a Stateless session bean. I was hoping there would be some kind of Interceptor of Listener system that I could hook into on the TransactionManager but there is nothing obvious that provides this. 
Is there any way to hook custom code after container commits/rolls back the transaction?

Comment: It is not clear to me when you say: "I have a requirement where I need to know when..."
The container will rollback the transaction if your code throws a SystemException or when you explicitly call 
EJBContext.setRollbackOnly() method. Otherwise, you know that the transaction is committed when the ejb business method is completed.

Comment: There is a custom locking mechanism that our application uses and the lock on the object must be released once the transaction is committed/ rolled back by Container. So i need to know any plug-gable means by which i can induce code after conainer/app server commits/Rollsback the JTA transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible way to solve by using `EJB-3 Interceptor`. I think, you would like to do something after process of the method.

```
public class MyInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        //Here before process of doSomething()
        Object result = ctx.proceed();
        //Here after process of  of doSomething()
        return result;
    }   
}


@Interceptors(MyInterceptor.class)
public <your-ejb-bean> {
    public void doSomething(){
    }
}
```